# Убрать за пределы экрана устройства

Tags: android, java

Никто не подскажет, как расположить элементы за пределами экрана?[image] Сделать так, как на картинке, я сделал для обычного смартфона, но когда открываешь на планшете, все элементы находятся в поле видимости, как это можно исправить?

```
    this.lx = gameView.getWidth() -100;
    this.rx = gameView.getWidth() + 800;        
    this.uy = gameView.getHeight() - 100;
    this.dy = gameView.getHeight() + 800;
```

Так я сделал для смарта, но это только для смарта, а на планшете жуть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже не буду спрашивать, зачем это могло понадобиться, но тут налицо неверный подход к разработке.

По сабжу - переводи абсолютные единицы в относительные (dip), умножая на плотность экрана.

Comment: Это все не на layout происходит, а на surfaceview, как Вы сказали не сделать.

Comment: Ну почему же не сделать?

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
this.lx = gameView.getWidth() - 100 * density;
this.rx = gameView.getWidth() + 800 * density;
this.uy = gameView.getHeight() - 100 * density;
this.dy = gameView.getHeight() + 800 * density;

Верный расчет и округление добавить самостоятельно.

Вообще, все проблемы от того, что вы привязываетесь к реальным единицам, которые могут и будут различаться на разных устройствах.